# ReactJS could not proxy request from localhost:3000 to localhost:3003

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockjs

I am writing a SPA using create-react-app and am using an expressjs server as my backend. For development I run my frontend test server on port 3000 and my backend expressjs test server on 3003.

I make many API calls client side using Axios so for development convenience I have defined proxy: "http://localhost:3003" in my package.json

This works fine on my laptop, but when running on my workstation I constantly get the error when accessing my app:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /sockjs-node/487/wrst1bub/websocket from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3003/. See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

I have no idea where this is coming from and I do not use sockjs in any capacity as far as I know. This is a console error and it does not crash my app but it is very annoying and I would like to get rid of it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Setting the proxy on the package.json did not work on an app I was developing. I configured the proxy myself and it did. Here's how: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually

Comment: I also had problems when using Firefox on one machine in particular: all my requests had error 405. Switching to another browser solved that for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using Firefox and for some reasons, it gives me the same error. I tried to use Chrome and it worked!

Comment: will you please provide the actual problem, that you are facing

Comment: In my case its opposite, works fine on firefox not on chrome