# Create React App not reloading with Express in development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I created a basic react app with Create React App. I removed all default files and added this into index file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
}

async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch('/express_backend');
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: json.express });
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>{this.state.data}</div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This app works. I can add some letters between divs and it reloads when saving. But when I add simple Express server the reloading stops. I also add `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"` into package.json inside CRA to connect server and client

Here is the server

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

// create a GET route
app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => {
res.send({ express: 'YOUR EXPRESS BACKEND IS CONNECTED TO REACT' });
});
```

I restarted both Create react app and server in console but now when I add smth between divs in the component nothing is reloading. I guess webpack dev server starts working improperly. 
How can I make reloading in CRA work and make request to express each time when I change smth in component?

Comment: I don't think `5000` is the standard port for webpack-dev-server so it's probably not a conflict between express and webpack. Do you notice any error in the console or in the network panel ?

Comment: I have no errors in console or anywhere.Everything is fine

Comment: Can you see your query being correctly returned from the server ?

Comment: yes it is returned from server. I see it on the screen

Comment: When you say the reloading stops, I'm assuming you just mean the react app isn't re-compiling and auto-updating changes upon save. Does this app utilize webpack-hot-middleware?

Comment: exactly. when i add smth in the component it is not recompiling. I dont know if this app utilize webpack-hot-middleware, I am just using whatever Create react app provides. I dont know for sure what is there under the hood

Comment: Actually there is some error in console. The connection to ws// localhost 3000 / socksjs-node blabla / websocket was interrupted while the page was loading. (red letters)

The development server was disconnected (black letters)

Comment: I found someone had the same problem : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55482914/reactjs-could-not-proxy-request-from-localhost3000-to-localhost3003

Comment: Could it be the name of your json return object property? Perhaps because the name is express, this is in conflict with the variable you declared named express. Maybe put express in quotes within the json object, or change the name.

Comment: I changed name from express to exp. The same thing. The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary. webpackHotDevClient.js:65

Comment: I just used this tutorial: https://dev.to/loujaybee/using-create-react-app-with-express  and it works great. Apperently, you'll need to run express and the react app in different processes (i.e different terminals). I'll tell you this, this thing lags pretty bad. I have a custom HMR setup with keystonejs and I don't experience any lag such as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running create-react-app with express, you'll need to run your server.js express app  in a separate node process than the react-js-app. Also, you'll need to specify the proxy in your package.json.

Utilize these commands in separate terminals:

```
node server.js
```

and in separate terminal:

```
npm start
```

Kudos to this tutorial: https://dev.to/loujaybee/using-create-react-app-with-express

Comment: I am sorry I didnt mention that I ran them in 2 terminals from the very start.

Comment: Weird, this was a very easy setup. Perhaps try changing from port 5000? I'm not sure what this project uses for webpack-dev-server port, but you never know. If this isn't the issue, I'm at a loss. You may want to start over and re-install all deps.